# How to manage phonegap deployment with new features of webkit

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, cordova, webkit

If I want to test and deploy a phonegap-based app which is dependent on a CSS feature for which support was added in the version of webkit that shipped with iOS 5,

1. Does a phonegap-built app include the build of webkit that it's built with, or does it use the version of webkit in the version of iOS on the device that it's installed on?
2. Depending on the answer above, how can I test it against older versions of iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap uses the current version of webkit on the OS. As far as older testing, best option is to check what features are available on the different versions of the iPhone. You should be pretty safe, but there will be a few things that will have limited support.